# How to use the same class attributes in different classes in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, mixins

I have 2 sets of attributes that I want to use in the same manner but in different classes. I am trying to mix in these sets as class attributes to avoid `super` calls and unnecessary complications:

```
class Base:
    def printAttr():
        print(attr)

class MixIn1:
    attr = "Monty"

class MixIn2:
    attr = "Python"

class Combo1(Base, MixIn1):
    pass

class Combo2(Base, MixIn2):
    pass

c1 = Combo1()
print(c1.attr) # it is assigned
c1.printAttr()
```

The result is `NameError: name 'attr' is not defined`. Obviously, it will work if I call `MixIn1.attr` explicitly, but it would be the same that putting this code to the class itself.

How can I use the same logic of processing for different `attr`s in an economic way?

Comment: The error does not match the code shown.

Comment: Please show actual code. The code you have posted would throw TypeError, because `printAttr` is missing the `self` parameter; and fixing that would then throw NameError, because `attr` is not defined in that method.

Comment: Also, you are missing a `self` parameter to the `printAttr` method.

Comment: Once you add the `self` parameter and access `self.attr`, it works fine. This looks like just carelessness on your part OP.

Comment: You can use `self`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the one positional argument (usually called `self`) required by a method, use it appropriately and it will work as you expect:

```
class Base:
    def printAttr(self):
        print(self.attr)

>>> c1 = Combo1()
>>> c1.printAttr()
Monty

>>> c2 = Combo2()
>>> c2.printAttr()
Python
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought that `self` was only needed for instance attributes, not class ones.

Answer (score 0):

A quick tip: Whenever you are using a function (method) under a class, always give 'self' in its parameters. This is a must for all methods. Infact, if you use Pycharm IDE, it auto-completes the self parameter.